# vb.net export datatable to excel wihtout excel installed

Tags: excel, vb.net, datatable

i have a little program that need to read, modify and save an excel file. this is the form_load code:

```
    DSet = New DataSet()
    DTable = New DataTable()
    Binding_Source = New BindingSource()

    Using myconnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & xlsfile & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'")
        Using mycommand As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table1$]", myconnection)
            mycommand.Fill(DTable)
            DSet.Tables.Add(DTable)
            Binding_Source.DataSource = DSet.Tables(0)
        End Using
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Binding_Source
```

what i want to do is to save the datagridview contents after any modification into an excel file (xls) without using the interop option, this because i don't have excel installed on every pc and can't install for license reasons.

there is a way to do?

i made a working "save button" using excel.iterop but on machine without excel application got an error & crash

thanks.

Comment: You can write a CSV file. There are a lot of libraries out there to help you in this.

Comment: i need a xls file not a csv

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without having Excel installed. What is the error exactly?